# Full calendar add an Event on multiple resources

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

How can I add an event on 2 or more resources? From what I have found on the internet, I can add an event on a resource, other event( or same event) on other resource. But how can I enlarge the same event on 2 resources?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, as described in the [Event Object Docu](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) an event can only have one Event Source.

What you can do, is to use the event callback functions to "push" a specific event also to another backend, when the event is created/rendered/updated.

Answer (score 0):

Ike Lin enhanced this full calendar for multiple resources. But it is only for day view I think.

[http://www.ikelin.com/jquery-fullcalendar-resource-day-view/]

Here is one more full calender which is even for month view for resources.

http://tux.fi/~jarnok/fullcalendar-resourceviews/